# JMeter: Stop test if the fail count rate is higher than success

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, beanshell

In JMeter,

I'm creating a test plan

In which I need to set a condition

(if the fail count rate is high than success, then I want my test to stop)

Tried :

- Auto-stop listener but its useful if we specify error rate %
- Tried bean shell post-processor but unsuccessful.

  if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
           prev.setStopThread(true);
      }

Any ideas much appreciated.! thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `setStopThread` you are "asking" JMeter to attempt to stop current thread only, the correct method would be [prev.setStopTest(true)](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setStopTest-boolean-). Again, if you call this method JMeter will "ask" threads to stop, if you want JMeter terminate in less graceful manner you can go for [prev.setStopTestNow(true)](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setStopTestNow-boolean-) method (you can get more failures this way as samplers will be abnormally terminated)

And finally you can call [System.exit(1)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#exit-int-) method which will **immediately** terminate the whole [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine).

---

Be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) [and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-blackhttps://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for scripting consider migrating from Beanshell to Groovy on next available opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use a test-action sampler, combined with an if-controller and an action stop:

1. Create an 'If Controller' and set your condition.
2. Create a 'Test Action' inside where your action is 'stop'.

Comment: Thanks. if it is if-controller 

* Is there any way to put condition like  if (pass < error) then stop using test action ?

Comment: Check how to use a counter in JMeter, i.e. https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test

Comment: Thanks i got answer.!